# Diagonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $D_{n}$ be the set of all n*n complex diagonal matrices. Does there exist a unitary matrix $U$ in $M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$  but not in $D_{n}$ such that $UD_{n}U^{*}= D_{n}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any permutation matrix will work. For instance
$$U=\pmatrix{0&1&0&\cdots&0\\
1&0&0&\cdots&0\\0&0&1&\cdots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\cdots&1}.$$